# $.when with dynamic input params and arguments

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a pool, where I store data, and iterate through on the items by cycles.

Limit is 3, so I get first trhee items, second three items, and the remaining items.

`ajax.php` is waiting seconds what comes from pool array. So the first cycle `1,2,4` should be released after `4` seconds, second is `2,1,4` also `4` seconds, and the remaining `3,1` is `3` seconds.

The problem is that `$.when` is get the ajax calls immediatly, even it they have do not has `responseText`. I'vd tried to add the `.apply` but in that case my browser is freezing...

It logs all the requests as object, but without responseText. When the 4 sec is loged, after 4 seconds the responseText is attached to it.

How can I solve this?

```
var queue = {
    limit: 3,
    pool: [
       1, 2, 4, 
       2, 1, 4, 
       3, 1
    ]
};


function startAjaxRequests() {
    var requests = [];
    while (queue.pool.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < queue.limit; i++) {
            if (typeof queue.pool[i] !== 'undefined') {
                requests.push($.get('/ajax.php', {secs: queue.pool[i]}, function () {}));
            }
        }
        $.when($, requests).done(function () {
        //$.when.apply(null, requests).done(function () {
            $.each(arguments, function (key, value) {
                console.log(value);
            });
            queue.pool.splice(0, queue.limit);
            requests = [];
        });
    }
    console.log('finish...');
}

startAjaxRequests();
```

If I am using like this:

```
var a1 = $.get('/ajax.php', {secs: 1});
var a2 = $.get('/ajax.php', {secs: 2});
var a3 = $.get('/ajax.php', {secs: 4});
$.when(a1, a2, a3).done(function () {
    $.each(arguments, function (key, value) {
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

then it works as it should, and console the results after 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'vd tried to add the .apply

That would be correct.

> but in that case my browser is freezing...

This is because of your `while` loop. Ajax (and `$.when`) is calling your callbacks **asynchronously**, so you already enter the next iteration before your pool ever empties - and that's effectively an infinite loop. Working with asynchronous code, you need to use a recursive approach instead of a synchronous loop.

```
function startAjaxRequests() {
    if (queue.pool.length > 0) {
        var requests = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < queue.limit; i++) {
            if (typeof queue.pool[i] !== 'undefined') {
                requests.push($.get('/ajax.php', {secs: queue.pool[i]}));
            }
        }
        $.when.apply($, requests).then(function () {
            $.each(arguments, function (key, value) {
                console.log(value);
            });
            queue.pool.splice(0, queue.limit);
            startAjaxRequests(); // recurse!
        });
    } else {
        console.log('finish...');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did put into a funcition, because I knew it should be recursive, silly me, I don't know how can I forget it. Thank you so much. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

`$.when` is asynchronous call, your queue may be empty before invoking second service request.

Comment: No, everything is fine with that. It logs all the requests as object, but without responseText. 4 sec is loged, and after 4 seconds the `responseText` is attached to it.

Comment: then check from server side, if there any issue, also don't forget to check response from client log

Comment: No issue at server side. It responses.

Comment: can you post the client log/response here